# Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(java.sql.SQLException, String)

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am trying to build a web application, I didn't add any classes or packages I have just ran the app but it says

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(java.sql.SQLException, String)" because the return value of "org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.sqlExceptionHelper()" is null
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:279) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:69) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:199) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:169) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1383) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1454) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1817) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1166) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:940) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:738) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:440) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at com.cafemanagementsystem.CafeManagementSystemProjectApplication.main(CafeManagementSystemProjectApplication.java:10)
```

The pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.cafemanagementsystem</groupId>
    <artifactId>CafeManagementSystemProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>CafeManagementSystemProject</name>
    <description>Cafe Management System Project using Spring Boot Framework.</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application properties

```
server.port = 6969
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/CafeManagementDatabase
spring.datasource.username = user
spring.datasource.password = 12345
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect.format_sql = true
```

```
package com.cafemanagementsystem;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CafeManagementSystemProjectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CafeManagementSystemProjectApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share the code in the class: CafeManagementSystemProjectApplication.java?

Comment: Hey @TimurCelikel I added the main method of the app

Comment: A NPE from the depths of a libraries code (Hibernate in this case) is a pretty good sign of a bug. Report it at https://hibernate.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/HHH/issues/?filter=allissues

Comment: Was this issue resolved? Or any workaround that was identified?

I am experiencing the exact same issue.

Comment: @DishantKamble I rebuilt the application from scratch, It might be a problem with some internal initializations, by that I mean everything was left as is nothing has changed in the code

Comment: Thats strange. I have rebuilt it from scratch multiple times, even tried backporting few dependnencies, but no luck.

I truly believe there is some configuration that I am missing, but i am not sure what. 

But i get the same error message as you did.

Comment: @DishantKamble Check if you are able to connect to the database using other tools. I faced similar issue while connecting my local springboot(version 3.3.0-SNAPSHOT) app to rds(postgres). Turns out that my security group didn't allow connection outside the default security group. Allowing my ip within the security group resolved the issue.

Comment: @JawadAboFakher Have you got solution, I am also stuck at same error. I am using spring 3.2.2 and oracle DB

Comment: make sure there isn't any issue when connecting to your database like your database name `CafeManagementDatabase`  matches on your database name on mysql. This happened to me when i used a database that didn't exist..

Answer (score 0):

Try this way as I got error during my docker run method which shown that port is not available.

**docker: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:3306 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.**

So I changed the port number to 3307 as follows:

**docker run --detach --env MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=hari --env MYSQL_USER=phani --env MYSQL_PASSWORD=hari --env MYSQL_DATABASE=shopping --name mysql --publish 3307:3306 mysql:8-oracle**

In your application.properties file change it to the port number you passed i.e.3307:

**spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/shopping**

Answer (score -2):

I'd just verify the DB credentials and URL.
I've ran into same problem, turns out the DB credentials in the docker image has been changed.